# Npgsql Entity Framework Core and version 1.1.2 of Entity Framework Core

Tags: npgsql

Newbie at C# and Visual studio so please be kind :)

At this site

http://www.npgsql.org/efcore/migration/1.1.html

it says that Version 1.1.0 of the Npgsql Entity Framework Core  works with version 1.1.0 of Entity Framework Core.

But when I pick Npgsql Entity Framework Core in Microsoft Visual studio (handle nuget packages) it says that a dependency is

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 1.1.0)

So should it work with 1.1.2 of Entity Framework Core? I do not get it to work at all and I just would like to know if anybody here use it together with 1.1.2 or if it's just not meant to be?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting an error message?

If you are receiving the following when you attempt to install the Nuget package, you need to ensure you are using Visual Studio 2017 15.3.0 or newer and .net Core.

> Error: Could not install package Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

I have found that to use Entity Framework Core, you have to use .Net Core, which requires that you use Visual Studio 2017 15.3.0 or newer.